# Reduce to upper triangular form.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

$$
        A= \begin{pmatrix}
        k & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
        1 & k & k & 1 \\
        0 & -1 & k+2 & 0 \\
        0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

I've tried multiple ways but I keep getting stuck after a few steps every path I try.

Answer (score 0):

Interchange first and second rows, and the proceed:

$$\begin{pmatrix}
1&k&k&1\\
k&0&1&1\\
0&\!-1&k+2&0\\
0&1&1&0\end{pmatrix}\stackrel{R_2-kR_1}\longrightarrow\begin{pmatrix}
1&k&k&1\\
0&\!-k^2&1-k^2&1-k\\
0&\!-1&k+2&0\\
0&1&1&0\end{pmatrix}\stackrel{R_2\leftrightarrow R_4}\longrightarrow$$$${}$$

$$\begin{pmatrix}
1&k&k&1\\
0&1&1&0\\
0&\!-1&k+2&0\\
0&\!-k^2&1-k^2&1-k
\end{pmatrix}\stackrel{R_3+R_2\;,\;R_4+k^2R_2}\longrightarrow\begin{pmatrix}
1&k&k&1\\
0&1&1&0\\
0&0&k+3&0\\
0&0&1&1-k
\end{pmatrix}\stackrel{R_3\leftrightarrow R_4}\longrightarrow$$$${}$$

$$\begin{pmatrix}
1&k&k&1\\
0&1&1&0\\
0&0&1&1-k\\
0&0&k+3&0
\end{pmatrix}\stackrel{R_4-(k+3)R_3}\longrightarrow\begin{pmatrix}
1&k&k&1\\
0&1&1&0\\
0&0&1&1-k\\
0&0&0&k^2+2k-3
\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: When you do the third step ( $R_4$ + $kR_2$ ) how do you get 1 for the fourth row third column? ( 1 x K + 1 - K^2 )

Comment: @user380468 That was a typo there that I shall edit now. It must be $\;R_4+k^2R_2\;$